# Getx update in context width change

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm kinda new to getX and I can not find an easy solution for updating certain widget when the context width changes. I already use the helper func responsiveValue but this does not trigger an event on context change.

Does anyone have experience with that ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Could you post your code on what have you tried please